# Backup and restore postgresql data folder directly

Tags: postgresql, docker

Till now I've been backing up my postgresql data using `pg_dump`, which exports the data to an sql file `mydb.sql`, and then restoring from that sql file using `psql -U user -d db < mydb.sql`.

For one reason or another it would be more convenient to restore the database content more directly, in an environment where `psql` does not exist... specifically on a host server where postgresql is installed in a docker container running on the host, but not on the host itself.

My plan is to back up the content of `/var/lib/postgresql/data/` to a tar file, and when required (e.g. when a new server is created that hosts the postgresql container) just restore that to the same path.  The folder `/var/lib/postgresql/data/` in the docker container is mapped to a folder on the host server, so I would create this backup on the host, not inside the postgres container.

Is this a valid approach?  Any "gotchas"?  And are there any subfolders within `/var/lib/postgresql/data/` that I can exclude from the tar file?  I don't want to back up mere 'housekeeping' information.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, but you have to do it properly if you don't want your database to become corrupted.

Either stop PostgreSQL before copying the data directory or follow the instructions from [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP) for an online backup.

Comment: Thanks, that link is a great help.  It looks like `pg_basebackup` might be the easiest way to go about it (I can shell into the postgres container to do this) and then use the output of that to restore the database.

Comment: ... though it's not clear to me what to do with the file `pg_wal.tar`

Comment: It contains the transaction log files required to recover the database to a consistent state.

Comment: And needs to be copied into `pg_wal/` folder when restoring?  When `pg_basebackup` is run without the `tar` option, the content of `pg_wal/` is OK, and can be restored without any further work?

Comment: Yes and yes. Directory mode is simpler.

Comment: So it seems easier to use `-F plain` (default) and then just `tar` the resulting folder... basically my intention is to send a `.tar.gz` backup file to a remote host, and fetch that when I need to restore, so it's easier not to use `-F tar -z` and instead do this myself before `curl`ing the gzipped tar file.  Is that sensible?  The restored database will be OK?